# AzureAD SAML and MFA

Tags: azure-active-directory, saml, multi-factor-authentication

I have a question about the SAML and MFA protocol. I have an app that acts as a ServiceProvider to an IdentityProvider, in my case AzureAD, and I would like to know if it is possible to insert some parameter/attribute in the SAML request that allows you to request the MFA during login on the IdP in order to request it when needed (under certain codes) and not always. It's possible to do it? Or is it something I can only set at the IdP level, so on AzureAD?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Azure AD MFA cannot be initiated on a per client request, it's initiated on a per tenant request.